# Change default chrome to TitleAndBorder on standard sharepoint web parts

Tags: web-part

Is there a way to change default chrome on **standard** web parts in sharepoint to "title and boarders" ?

I know how to change the chrome in a standard web part, but how can I set it as default when adding new web part (titleandboarders).

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you find a solution to change the default setting ? Regards, Laurent

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/de7e3203-f88f-458f-b233-5c4e53733ac6) suggestion of exporting the web part with its chrome setting set to what you want the default to be, and then upload it to the Web Part Gallery. It should keep the chrome setting as defined in the .webpart/.dwp file so if a user adds it to a page it will show your selected chrome first.